# Curl request showing different content from that of browser request

Tags: php, curl

When I type a URL into my browser, it returns detailed output. However, when I try to do this by a curl request, the request is empty. Why this is happening?

URL is https://api.500px.com/v1/users?oauth_token=AihBz6ZWedu3VxnQdy2tqWtbwV86wtOuXumhPapk&oauth_verifier=YhKo0kaGhfw0dFhparxU&consumer_key=0OvWThqr5j1ZYX1cPaa8y0y1aOfJBbDtpX85fJ42

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<?php



function fetchData($url) {
             $ch = curl_init();
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $returned = curl_exec($ch);
   echo 'Errors: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br><br>';
   curl_close ($ch);
   echo $returned;
             return $returned;
    }


);
        // Pulls and parses data.

    $returned = fetchData("https://api.500px.com/v1/users?oauth_token=xElRwQ6cqItG8Siy9kFBpwkj5sCdlp33NRva5TZU&oauth_verifier=hbNdYnqm8BSyuiZYa4KZ&consumer_key=0OvWThqr5j1ZYX1cPaa8y0y1aOfJBbDtpX85fJ42");
    var_dump($returned);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
    $result = json_decode($returned);
        print_r($returned);



// if(!curl_errno($ch))
// {
//  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

//  echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
// }

echo "working";
echo curl_error($ch);
echo "workign4";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); 
echo "working6";



?>


</html>
```

Comment: I should add the url works one time. If someone types it in, new key codes need to be generated.

Comment: Can you post what is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I'm not getting an error. The request returns a single blank space when done with curl. When done manually, it returns no error. It returns a bunch of info about the user.

Comment: So why did you written this title `Odd URL + Curl Error Php`?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar. I mean. It's supposed to return a bunch of info about the user and it's not. There's no formal error from using the error function, but it does not return the same output, as it would manually. So, there's an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Making request through cURL and manually in browser can display different contents even if you have submitted the same URL parameters in both cases. The reasons can be few.

- POST Data: Your browser is sending some POST data which you forgot to send in case of cURL.
- Cookie: Your web browser is sending some cookie to the server which is required for the content to display.
- IP: It is not a trouble in case of local server but can vary in case of a web host.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to get the same output as manually?

Comment: @user1605871 Try to solve these problems. They are tools like HTTP Analyzer which can help you solve these problems.

Comment: Which http analyzer do you recommend? There seem to be several.

Comment: @VargunAgw Do you know of any alternatives to curl besides wget and filegetcontents() which may work in php?