# curl php empty blank space

Tags: php, curl

When I type a URL into my browser, it returns detailed output. However, when I try to do this by a curl request, the request returns a single empty blank space. Why this is happening?

URL is https://api.500px.com/v1/users?oauth_token=AihBz6ZWedu3VxnQdy2tqWtbwV86wtOuXumhPapk&oauth_verifier=YhKo0kaGhfw0dFhparxU&consumer_key=0OvWThqr5j1ZYX1cPaa8y0y1aOfJBbDtpX85fJ42

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<?php



function fetchData($url) {
             $ch = curl_init();
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $returned = curl_exec($ch);
   echo 'Errors: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br><br>';
   curl_close ($ch);
   echo $returned;
             return $returned;
    }


);
        // Pulls and parses data.

    $returned = fetchData("https://api.500px.com/v1/users?oauth_token=xElRwQ6cqItG8Siy9kFBpwkj5sCdlp33NRva5TZU&oauth_verifier=hbNdYnqm8BSyuiZYa4KZ&consumer_key=0OvWThqr5j1ZYX1cPaa8y0y1aOfJBbDtpX85fJ42");
    var_dump($returned);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: The url I'm following is giving me a blank page

Comment: @StephenTG Sorry the access codes are only good one time, meaning someone else clicked on the link. I'll send you one now.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem...

Comment: @StephenTG Try this: https://api.500px.com/v1/users?oauth_token=C8eEoDAFVcOoA7cdbncYNQ6Xqn6fO61nZC94XofY&oauth_verifier=Ty6NTE2uDOeXTZdoCsT9&consumer_key=0OvWThqr5j1ZYX1cPaa8y0y1aOfJBbDtpX85fJ42

Comment: @StephenTG Is there a way I can message you separate?

Comment: Not sure. However, I feel like the fact that each link is only good once could be what's causing the curl to fail. I don't really have all that much evidence to back it up, though.

Comment: Why don't you follow their instructions for their API ?  [https://github.com/500px/api-documentation/blob/master/examples/PHP/PHP.md](https://github.com/500px/api-documentation/blob/master/examples/PHP/PHP.md)

Comment: @ChrisMorrissey That link's a deadend for me

Comment: @ChrisMorrissey I retrieve the oauth and verifier code using that. However, I need to do a separate curl request to get user info. I wrote this myself. Couldn't figure out how to do it with the link.

Comment: Why don't you follow their instructions for their API ?  https://github.com/500px/api-documentation/blob/master/examples/PHP/PHP.md

Comment: $content  = $connection->get('users');

Comment: What is this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737909/curl-request-showing-different-content-from-that-of-browser-request/

Answer (score 0):

Please use CURLOPT_HEADER to check the response headers for any errors.

Comment: so set this  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); ?

Comment: I'm getting this: HTTP Error 411 Length required

Answer (score 0):

Use curl in following format -

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'client='.$number.'&order='.$orderId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
$data =curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: what's the point of curlopt_useragent?

Comment: When a URL is requested via cURL , the server responds to the request like a request sent via browser. However, the default cURL request do not specify information which is needed by some servers to validate a request, for eg. User Agent, language etc.

Comment: this code doesn't work. I modified it for my exmaple and it returns at 500px page that says oops there must have been an error.